# how to preselect a value in ListBox in MS-Access form?

Tags: vba, ms-access

Trying to preselect one value in a single-select ListBox (`.MultiSelect = False`) in MS-Access (current 365) by code, I found that setting `.Selection(i)` may lead to inconsistencies if mixed with using `.Value` instead of `.ItemData(i)`:

- Setting `.Seletion(i)` does *not* set `.Value` but highlights the row (so the user must think that value is selected).
- Setting `.Value` to a *value that is not in the list* (which is possible!) removes the selection (=> could be used as a test of a value against the list: set `.Value` and check `If .ItemsSelected.Count > 0`).
- `.Selected(i)` always matches `.ItemData(i)` => maybe more failsafe approach?

Test code (to see highlighting behaviour you need to comment out some steps):

```
Private Sub cmdTest_Click()
    With Me.lstSingle
        FillList ' "eins", "zwei", "drei", "vier" (code see below)
        Debug.Print ".ItemData(1)", ".Value", "Selected(1)", "Selected(2)"
        ' note: rows count from 0

        Debug.Print .ItemData(1), .Value, .Selected(1), .Selected(2)
        ' result:   zwei          Null    0             0             no selection shown

        .Value = "test" ' assign a value not in the list
        Debug.Print .ItemData(1), .Value, .Selected(1), .Selected(2)
        ' result:   zwei          test    0             0             no selection shown

        .Selected(1) = True ' set selection on second row
        Debug.Print .ItemData(1), .Value, .Selected(1), .Selected(2)
        ' result:   zwei          test     -1           0             second row highlighted
        '                         ^^^^                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        .Value = "drei" ' assign a value that is in the list
        Debug.Print .ItemData(1), .Value, .Selected(1), .Selected(2)
        ' result:   zwei          drei     0            -1            third row highlighted

        .Selected(1) = True ' set selection back on second row
        Debug.Print .ItemData(1), .Value, .Selected(1), .Selected(2)
        ' result:   zwei          drei    -1             0            second row highlighted
        '                         ^^^^                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        .Value = "test" ' assign a value not in the list (again)
        Debug.Print .ItemData(1), .Value, .Selected(1), .Selected(2)
        ' result:   zwei          test    0             0             no selection shown
    End With
End Sub

'results compared
'.ItemData(1)  .Value  Selected(1)  Selected(2)
'zwei          Null    0            0             no selection shown
'zwei          test    0            0             no selection shown
'zwei          test    -1           0             second row highlighted
'zwei          drei    0            -1            third row highlighted
'zwei          drei    -1           0             second row highlighted
'zwei          test    0            0             no selection shown


Private Sub FillList()
    With Me.lstSingle
        ' clear list
        .RowSource = vbNullString

        ' fill list
        Dim vA As Variant
        vA = Array("eins", "zwei", "drei", "vier")
        Dim i As Long
        For i = LBound(vA) To UBound(vA)
            .AddItem vA(i)
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

What would be best practice for preselecting a value in a `ListBox`control?

Comment: Interesting observation, but what's your question? Not everything in Access is implemented equally well, if you run tests like this on a multivalued combo box it gets even more funky.

Comment: @Erik: I wanted to share (1) to possibly learn about something I misunderstood, (2) document the problem because people search here and I couldn't find anything about this. Hope this is in the interest of the community although in this case I don't need help to find a way out.

Comment: You better make sure it fits the Q&A format (which it currently doesn't), it's currently at 2 close votes and will get automatically deleted some time after it's closed.

Comment: @Erik A: Ok, I rewrote - hope that fit's in community rules.

Comment: Seems fine to me now, if it does get closed (close votes can't get cleared and it only needs one more), @ping me for a reopen vote

Comment: Thank you for both, reviewing and offering me a reopen vote in case needed! I'd be happy if I might contribute something useful although not yet experienced enough to answer other peoples questions, as far as I tried.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I also learned this (the hard way) a long time ago.

But you already answered your question: Setting `.Value` is the way to go.
Especially if you will read the value later, and the user may never change the default selection.

Comment: setting `.Value` or (if, for any reason, working with the index is more handy) consequently use `.ItemData(i)` together with `.Selected(i)`, right? In my case, I knew the row index to preselect but I didn't know the value of that row, so I would have had to code some extra lines to get the value of that row in order to be able to select it by setting `.Value`. It took me a while to nail down the problem and I couldn't find anything about this here on SO - the reason I asked was primarily to document this here for others ;)

Comment: setting `.Value = .ItemData(i)` would bee the failsafe approach in that case, I think.